# Как изменять текст кнопки по нажатию в Telebot

Tags: python, button, telebot, бот

Я уже несколько дней думаю, в интернете ищу, но никак не могу понять как по нажатию на кнопку изменить ее текст. Работаю, сообственно, с pyTelegramAPI в питоне. Вот кусок кода:

```
weather = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
weather.add(
    types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'Сейчас', callback_data='weather_now'))
```

Сверху меню, а при обработке кнопки вот код:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def handler_call(call):
        chat_id = call.message.chat.id
        message_id = call.message.message_id
        if call.data == 'weather_now':
            g = get_weather_now()    # Функция для получения погоды
            bot.edit_message_text(
                chat_id=chat_id,
                message_id=message_id,
                text=g,
                reply_markup=weather,
                parse_mode='Markdown')
```

***Если у кого есть идеи, пишите***

Comment: Поставить обработчик, который будет реагировать на нажатие этой кнопки и отсылать новый набор кнопок, с уже измененным текстом. Не отсылая заново клавиатуру не изменить текст

Answer (score 2, accepted):

определите функцию, которая будет возвращать вам клавиатуру, с аргументом:

```
def weather_key(text):
    weather = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    weather.add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=text, callback_data='weather_now'))
    return weather
```

этот аргумент используйте в `text=` и:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['123'])
def handle_docs_photo(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'текст над кнопкой', reply_markup=weather_func('lalala'))

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def handler_call(call):
    if call.data == 'weather_now':
        bot.edit_message_text(
            chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
            message_id=call.message.message_id,
            text=get_weather_now(),
            reply_markup=weather_func('blala'),
            parse_mode='Markdown')
```